# Are there "banks" (or something morally equivalent) which merely stores their clients' money and doesn't invest/lend/etc it?

Tags: banking, bankruptcy

Another year, another major bank or two goes down because it decided to take the money that it was entrusted with it and go gamble. All of them fear "bank runs" because they know that they can't give back all the money that was entrusted to them at the same time, since they're using some of it for side hustles.

Which makes me wonder - are there any financial institutions which make a point of simply being a storage unit and nothing else? Like, I can open an account there and I can pay money into the account, and I can get a card to pay with which is linked to that account - but I can also rest assured that the money will be there when I want it. This institution would give no loans or credits of any sort, and never pay any interest rates on any deposits. It would not invest the money entrusted to it or do anything else with it besides just storing it. Basically it would be the digital equivalent of the proverbial mattress.

It would subsist solely on fees for maintaining the accounts. Understandably, these fees would be larger than in other "regular" banks, but that would be the price of stability. No bank run or economic instability would be able to touch it.

Somehow I've never heard of anything like that. Why is that?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Whoops! How did I mess up which site I ask on?! Sorry, deleting this!

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Ack, cannot delete this anymore since someone already answered it. Maybe it can be migrated?

Comment: 1. How in your opinion did SVB gamble with depositors money? 2. Where do banks get the money to loan to people?  3. Go watch It’s A Wonderful Life; specifically the part where George tells people where their money is.

Comment: The question is based on an incorrect assumption, and shows very little understanding of real world banking activity.

Comment: can people please quit with the "OMG the banks are unsafe" fear mongering?  It is ill-informed ignorance to the point of intentionally lying. Banks don't decide to "go gamble". There haven't been any bank failures since the Great Recession.  SVB's investments weren't unreasonable at all, they just weren't very liquid.  Also if you're in the wrong site you don't delete and repost, you "flag"..."mod assist"... "please xfer to desired destination".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "Banks don't decide to "go gamble"." Yes, they do. All investment is gambling. The only question is what the odds and rates of return are.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I did the Flag thing as soon as I realized I had misposted. As for gambling - yes, I consider investing (and even loaning to other people) as "gambling", because there is a very real risk (even if small) that the money money might be lost.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica As for fearmongering - go after the news websites then. Or better yet - reality itself. I'm not just speaking about the USA (although, yes, it's what prompted me to ask this question) but in general. Banks have been going down in US and in other countries too, for years. Sure, _some_ of the funds are protected, but not all, and reclaiming them can be a lengthy bureaucratic effort (again, depending on where you are) - something not all people can afford.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica And for the record - I still consider using a bank safer than just putting the money in a sock. It's just that even this option leaves something to desire. (I also have a few other personal reasons why a "storage-only" solution would appeal to me, but that's beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: You misunderstand the word "gamble".  Basically, risks are *calculated*, but gambling is *pure chance*.

Comment: @RonJohn - doesn't make me feel more comfortable to know that someone is taking my money (without my permission no less, although it's probably written somewhere in the fine print) and making "calculated risk maneuvers" with it. Call it what you like, I'd prefer them to NOT do it.

Comment: @Vilx- "someone is *taking my money* (without my permission no less...)" Double LOL.  **You gave it to them**, remember?

Comment: @Vilx- "and making "calculated risk maneuvers" with it."  Have you ever borrowed money?

Comment: @Nick012000 Clearly you're not a manager of an endowment.  There is law *requiring* you invest it certain ways. So no, all investing is not gambling.  Or if you want to be existentialist about it, every choice you make with money is gambling, and the "do not gamble" option does not exist!

Comment: @RonJohn I gave it to them **for safekeeping**. And for the convenience of having a payment card. Not for them to lend it out to someone I don't know. Not for them to buy stocks or bonds or bottlecaps or whatever. That's the point. And, yes, I have borrowed money. I'm not happy to do that, but I have. Still, when I do so, I would expect that the bank puts its own money on the line, not the money of its clients.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica ... this whole post is me asking to educate me about where I am wrong. I know I am wrong. I know I'm alone in these views and that it's most likely because I've misunderstood something. I'm eagerly displaying everything that I don't know/like in hopes that someone will come along and point out my errors. But I do want them to actually _convince_ me of their truth with facts and explanations, not just bashing me for not understanding what it's all about.

Comment: @Vilx- "I gave it to them for safekeeping."  Guess what?  (In the US, at least; can't answer about unspecified places around the world) your money *is* safe.

Comment: @Vilx- "this whole post is me asking to educate me about where I am wrong." And yet you keep arguing about what banks *should be*.

Comment: OK, deep breaths... Slowly... Several things now. A) First of all, my question was a very simple and respectful one - "Is there an institution that fits this description? If not, why not?" The rest of the flame is down here in the comments and borderline off-topic to begin with. My original question explicitly asks for an explanation of what I've gotten wrong (that is, **WHY** there isn't such a thing that I've imagined). [Contd]

Comment: B) Yes, I do intend to argue with people. I want to hear arguments and present counter-arguments and get counter-counter-arguments, etc. until I am presented with something that I cannot object to anymore. That's what I mean by "a convincing argument". I want to gain understanding this way. I have not - and never will - insult people or call names or whatever. I respect you all, you are smarter than me. But I do hope to mercilessly assault your ideas and arguments and expect to receive the same in return. [Contd]

Comment: Yes, this is a somewhat emotional topic for me (and it ties in with several others I haven't even mentioned yet because they would be completely off-topic) and I won't hide it. But that should make it all the easier to dismantle my ideas. And - to be honest - I've gotten to this point only because I've never had anyone to talk about this to. And lastly C) If you still don't like it, as I said before, this is getting really, really, off-topic. There's actually no need to discuss just _how safe_ money is in a bank or what is right and wrong, etc. The stated question doesn't ask for that.

Comment: P.S. I changed the title to remove the word "gambling". I don't know what else might be offensive and/or attention-grabbing about it.

Comment: "I don't know what else might be offensive and/or attention-grabbing about (gambling)."  You *still* don't seem to understand that risk is not the same as gambling.

Comment: "I want to hear arguments and present counter-arguments ... until I am presented with something that I cannot object to anymore."  You're ***not*** arguing with our definition of *bank* (organization who receives voluntary deposits from people/groups, and turns around to loan that money to other people/group); you're petulantly stomping your feet and shouting "I don't like that!  Make it different!"

Comment: @RonJohn - Sorry, poor choice of words on my part. I mean "I don't know what else might be offensive and/or attention-grabbing about (the title of this question after editing it)". The rest seems to be... terminology. I'm ok with not calling it "gambling", but it is a voluntary action that takes a risk in hopes to gain rewards for it which is... very  similar to gambling, in my eyes (except the odds are better and well calculated, of course, but still, the underlying principle is the same). I'm also OK with not calling my proposed institution a "bank". I just don't have a better name for it.

Comment: @RonJohn The failure of SVB because it was gambling with people's money is evidence that it isn't.

Comment: @nick012000 you also misunderstand the difference between risk and gamble.

Comment: @RonJohn There is no difference. All risks are gambles. There's only bigger and smaller gambles, with bigger and smaller payoffs if you win.

Comment: @nick012000 risks are calculated; gambles are pure chance.  (I know what you’re going to say… calculations can be imperfect or based on irrational, fraudulent or biased data.)

Comment: This is just nitpicking about terminology now.

Comment: @Vilx- words have meaning.  Without those meanings, we can’t clearly communicate.

Comment: Does something like PayPal satisfy your requirements?  They hold your money, but do not loan it out, allow you to make payments and transfers, and in the US are licensed and regulated as a money transfer service, not as a bank.

Comment: @RonJohn True, true. Carry on. 

Comment: @Nobody Hmm, actually, it almost does, except it doesn't issue payment cards AFAIK. And I'm not sure if you can do regular bank transfers to/from them easily.

Comment: I would consider a bank putting deposits only into short-term government bonds to be a fully-reserved bank. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-reserve_banking . But if the local currency had an extremely large amount of inflation then just holding the number amount of the local currency would be financial failure for the depositor. That's true if the interest rate doesn't match the inflation rate and some don't.

Comment: @Vilx: Yes, you can do bank transfers to/from PayPal, or at least I can here in the US. It happens as authorized debits and credits rather than as inter-bank transfer (in other words, the say way auto-billing runs when you authorize any other company to initiate transfers on your behalf), but it happens and the end user really doesn't see much difference. But of course PayPal isn't "just holding" the money either. While they have it, they undoubtedly invest it appropriately and pocket the returns. Do you really trust them more than you trust a bank? If so, wanna buy a toll bridge, cheap?

Comment: @keshlam - didn't get the toll bridge reference. As for trust - they've been around long enough (and I use their services regularly too) that yes, I trust them as much as my bank. But not more, I think. (What I certainly _don't_ trust are random keshlams on the Internet trying to sell me things cheap. )

Comment: I would trust PayPal significantly less, but on your head be it. The point about the toll bridge is exactly your final point: I think you are being misled into worrying about the wrong things, exactly as if someone was trying to sell you something that they had no right to sell.

Comment: @keshlam Modern banking is... complicated. I have only the foggiest idea how it works and that alone makes me uneasy. A part of the appeal for the "storage solution" is that it would be a lot simpler. And sure, there are bad actors everywhere - if I give my money for someone to keep there's always the risk they'll just take my money and disappear with it into the sunset. To make it safer there are only two things that I can think of - government oversight (but then I need to trust the goverment) and a good, long reputation. But this applies equally to banks as well.

Comment: Banks have longer and better reputations than PayPal. You are REALLY worrying about the wrong things. Modern banking, at least in the US, is insured, and can be further insured by distributing your money among several banks so you always have working capital even if you do need to rely on that insurance. And your choice of bank also gives you some degree of control. I might have my doubts about _investing_ in some banks operating in the US; I have zero doubts about depositing any "normal" amount of money in almost any of them.

Comment: @keshlam I'm from Europe. But, don't get me wrong - I don't _distrust_ banks. I use them daily myself! Heck, I barely do anything with cash at all! This question was more in the vein of "but is there maybe something even better?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We call such institutions "[safe deposit boxes](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/banking/what-is-safe-deposit-box)." There is no version of a true equivalent to a safe deposit box that is widely available to the public and accessible via an electronic transfer in the United States. And, among muggles without access to [Gringotts Wizarding Bank](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Gringotts_Wizarding_Bank), very few people manage their cash savings that way. In part, this is because this children's book financial institution runs in a way that children and other people who don't understand banking think that banks work, even though they really don't work that way (and ultimately can't work that way at a macroeconomic level).

In many countries outside the United States, government run [postal service banking systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_savings_system) with savings accounts from which you can make payments via a money order like document sometimes called a [giro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giro_(banking)) serve this purpose. Giro based payments through a postal banking system was the main means by which consumer payments were processed, in the era when U.S. consumers made payments with checks drawn on commercial bank deposit accounts, in much of the world. Some of these systems now allow for electronic fund transfers. The first postal banking system was established [in Great Britain in 1861](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_savings_system).

In Japan, for example, where [this system was established in 1875](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Post_Bank), there have been times in recent history (I don't know if it is still true) when most household savings were in the form of deposit accounts with the postal system. [As of March 3, 2006](https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/publications/economic-letter/2006/march/postal-savings-in-japan-and-mortgage-markets-in-the-us/), the Japanese people had "about ¥330 trillion in assets, which is roughly 65% of Japan’s GDP" in aggregate postal savings account balances. (Incomplete efforts to privatize this system started in 2005 but the government still owns a majority of the postal banking system.)

[Western Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Union) in the United States was an attempt to imitate a postal banking system in the private sector, but it has never really gained a large market share outside the niche of international remittance payments to expatriates homelands.

None of these systems, however, is truly loan free or risk free, although they invest the savings of their customers in very low risk investments which are sometimes guaranteed by the government. Money in a modern economy is predominantly [just negotiable third-party debt](https://wfhummel.net/moneyasdebt.html).

[At the macroeconomic level of an entire economy, savings accounts and investments in real world economic assets are two inextricably tied sides of the same coin](https://www.albany.edu/%7Ebd445/Economics_301_Intermediate_Macroeconomics_Slides_Spring_2014/Saving_Equals_Investment.pdf), however indirectly. Savings are a right to something of value in the future, but at any given moment in time, all real world assets have to be in use by someone. Real world goods and services can't miraculously time travel to the future from the time that you want to save money for future purposes. All of the goods and services available in the economy at any given time have to exist or be replaced by substitute real world goods and services at every moment of time between the time when you forego consumption by saving and the time when you want to withdraw your savings to consume real world goods and services.

In American popular culture, the classic illustration of the concept that savings are ultimately impossible to segregate from real world investments is [a speech by George in the classic 1946 movie "It's A Wonderful Life"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTJCI1FNBfA) (paraphrased [here](https://www.zocalopublicsquare.org/2018/12/06/george-baileys-building-loan-company-can-still-teach-us-banking/ideas/essay/)), in which he explains to people in the midst of a run on a bank how their money isn't sitting in the safe but is instead tied up in mortgages on houses and the like. The [key portion of the script](https://goosecreekplayers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/2011-12-Wonderful-Life-script-original.pdf) for this purpose says:

> MISS ANDREWS. But I’ve got my money here, George, and I’ll take it
> now.
>
> GEORGE. No. Miss Andrews, you’re thinking of this place all wrong. As
> if I had the  money back in the safe. The money’s not here. Your
> money’s in the Grange’s house right next to yours. And in the Kennedy
> house, and Mrs. Macklin’s house, and a hundred others. Why, you’re
> lending them the money to build, and then, they’re going to pay it
> back to you as best they can. Now what are you going to do? Foreclose
> on them?

In the case of commodities (like gold) negotiable [warehouse receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_receipt) are used in a similar way to a safe deposit box.

In the case of securities, a "[nominee](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nominee.asp)" holder often serves a safe deposit box like role. There is also [a little known government agency](https://www.sipc.org/about-sipc/) that protects customers of these firms from events that deprive them of their securities (like embezzlement or destruction of stock certificates), in a way similar to the way that the FDIC protects commercial bank depositors.

An account in a [Federal Deposit Insurance Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Deposit_Insurance_Corporation) (FDIC) insured commercial bank up to the insured dollar amount is functionally equivalent although the "back office" way that it gets to functional equivalency is not the situation that you contemplate. Consumer authorized electronic fund transfers from commercial bank accounts insured by the FDIC, while they have had [a legal framework in place for decades](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4a/article4a), have only very recently been used on a widespread basis by ordinary banking industry customers.

The existence of equivalents (from the small customer's perspective) like the FDIC insured banks is the operational reason that this isn't done, even though the macroeconomic link between savings and investments is the fundamental reason that this is the case. Borrowing cheap and lending high is [a large share of the profit of a commercial bank](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/commercialbank.asp) that subsidizes its ordinary customer deposit account operations. Withdrawing this revenue stream would make it economically non-viable in competition with firms that do so.

Comment: SDBs are *worse* than bank accounts, because they have **NO** protection.  They get accidentally drilled into All. The. Time., get lost, etc, etc.

Comment: @RonJohn Safe deposit boxes are quite secure so long as you hold onto the key and know the box number and street address of it. I've been a lawyer since 1995 and have never encountered a problem with one or met a lawyer who'd ever had a problem with one or seen a media report or court case with a problem with one - apart from dead people who don't tell their heirs where it is and lose the key (in which case it is drilled). Natural disasters or building fires or failures that compromise safe deposit boxes are very, very rare in most places. Theft/fraud by family/employees also happens.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/19/business/safe-deposit-box-theft.html "In Maryland, a large bank closed several branches and lost track of hundreds of safe deposit boxes, according to a lawsuit filed by a customer who said he lost gold and gems valued at $500,000."

Comment: @RonJohn Everything that is possible happens sometime or other, even if its very are (you hear about every shark attack death but very rarely about the vastly more common deaths caused by angry cows). But even then the bank had legal liability to those safe deposit box holders and probably had insurance to cover the loss as well. Banks go under but have to make good to harmed depositors from FDIC etc. too.

Comment: "I've been a lawyer *since 1995* ... *or seen a media report or court case* with a problem with one".  They're all over the media.

Comment: @RonJohn Clearly I read different media than you do or just haven't noticed those stories in the daily torrent of news.

Comment: Being condescending to anyone who chooses to use this hypothetical service is not helpful to your answer. Yeah, banking works this way - because people to store their money in this type of bank. The question asks if there is also a different type of bank the beginning of your answer amounts to "there is no other type of bank because *normal people* use this type and *only children* would want to use the other type"

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted savings=investment, as both "savings" and "investment" in economics do not solely refer to financial instruments. When you produce something and do not immediately consume it, that is economic savings and investment. Baking a cake is savings and investment.

Comment: @user253751 your answer amounts to "there is no other type of bank because normal people use this type and only children would want to use the other type" No.  What I am doing is comparing child level understanding of what banking is to an informed level understanding of what banking is at a very intrinsic level. And, while savings and investment indeed do not have to be financial or monetary in character, in a modern economy, saving and investment are heavily monetized so its a good understandable example.

Comment: @ohwilleke The asker understands how banking works and they are asking if there is also a different type of institution that is similar to a bank but works differently. Whether you call that institution a "bank" or not is irrelevant

Comment: >at any given moment in time, all real world assets have to be in use by someone

This is simply false. If I put 20 000$ or 2 kg of lithium in my basement then they are not in use by anyone. They are simply removed from the circulation for the time they are stored.

Comment: @Bartos LIthium yes. The cash is really a form of negotiable debt.

Answer (score 13):

Why would you want that?

Banks don't "gamble", banks do what they're supposed to be doing: borrowing from those who have extra cash to lend to those who have not enough and earning the arbitrage on the interest difference and fees from both sides.

If you're looking for a bank that would just store your pile of cash - you'd need to pay that bank significant amounts for the service. You'd need to finance their operations, their expenses, their security and safety (after all, you don't want your proverbial mattress robbed or stolen), and provide them additional money as profit so that it would be worth their while to store your pile of cash. As the result, your pile of cash would erode, significantly and at high rate.

The way the banking system works is that you pay for the service not by reducing your balance but instead by allowing the bank using your cash while you don't. Sure, in some banks and in some countries they still charge fees from depositors, but even there if you deposit high enough amounts the fees diminish or disappear altogether.

Retail investors are insured by governments and central banks in case of bank collapses, and those with high enough balances that exceed the insurance have means to protect themselves (either by diversifying the deposits, or by getting their own private insurance).

In any case, as the examples of the three largest bank failures in the US show, the depositors are the last to get hurt even when the banks do fail. So I see no reason why you'd want to fund a bank operation and profits out of your own pocket - what would the benefit to you be?

---

The other answer mentions postal financial systems as an alternative. This is a slightly different system than a commercial bank. These are usually subsidized by governments and are created to allow access to banking services for all (given the prevalence of postal branches compared to commercial banks at the time). In many countries the postal banks have become regular banks for all intents and purposes, in others they still exist and provide mostly basic services (cash deposits/withdrawals, bill payments, etc). People with high cash balances would probably be lacking a lot of services through these systems that they'd need.

Comment: For small depositors (aka your average Joe living from paycheck to paycheck and having all their eggs in one basket) the benefit would be that they wouldn't risk suddenly being cut off from all their money for weeks or months until the bureaucratic procedures resolve. For large depositors the benefit would be that _all_ of their deposit would be protected, not only the first $10,000 or whatever (depends on the local legislature).

Comment: Also, I wonder how big would the fees have to get in order to make such a business sustainable?

Comment: @Vilx - In the US, small depositors aren't cut off from their money any more than they are when one bank merges with another.  The old bank closes on Friday, it opens on Monday under new management, and everything just works.  As for fees, Bank of America had ~80 B in operating expenses and ~37 M depositors in 2022 which would be a $2000 fee per depositor if spread evenly.  If half those expenses are eliminated by eliminating all loans, that's still $1000 per depositor.  That's in the ballpark- banks generally expect it to cost a couple hundred dollars a year to manage a checking account.

Comment: @JustinCave - OK, that's at least a number! Somewhat high, as expected, but I believe it would be possible to reduce it quite a bit with a dedicated effort.

Comment: @Vilx- It's unlikely that you're going to drastically reduce the cost.  If BoA was able to cut the cost of running a checking account, they have every incentive to do that.  It would be less expensive if you didn't need brick and mortar branches, phone support for issues, you didn't need to mail out statements, etc.  But doing that rules out reasonably large segments of the population who want/ need those services.

Comment: @JustinCave - I was thinking along those lines, yes. Most transactions electronic; few branches; as cashless as possible. No own ATMs, cash can be withdrawn via VISA/Mastercard/AmericanExpress/whatever networks in whatever ATM (but with the withdrawal fees).

Comment: @Vilx- the first $250,000 you wanted to say. As I said before and will say again - no depositor has been cut off from their money no matter the amount, let alone the insured ones (all the average Joe's and some more).

Comment: @littleadv I'm not really talking about this particular bank issue. In fact, I'm not even (directly) affected by it - I live on the other side of the world. And, really, it's great that everyone is protected from the fallout this time. That's awesome. My question was a more generic one. I've seen bank crashes for other reasons where people weren't so lucky (including one a few years ago in my own country).

Comment: @Vilx- It's hard to address concerns that you have specifically about your country when you don't disclose any details of your situation. There are about 200 countries in the world, some with better protections for consumers than others. So you'd probably get a more useful answer if you'd provide more specific details.

Comment: @Vilx- you want an Islamic "bank".

Comment: @littleadv - I don't have any concerns about customer protection or whatever. :) My question was about whether there is some sort of bank-like business which does ONLY money storage without all the other stuff that banks do.

Comment: @Vilx- "bank-like business ... without the other stuff that banks do"  you see the problem with your question, don't you? The "other" stuff that banks do *is* what banks *are*.

Comment: @RonJohn Islamic banks are actually much more risky. Instead of lending they're partnering in ownership.

Comment: OP has the crazy notion that banks "tak(e) my money (without my permission no less...)".  That wouldn't happen with an Islamic bank.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't understand this statement. Islamic bank is still a bank. The Sharia prohibits charging interest, but that's all. Islamic banks invest instead of lending, which is inherently more risky.

Comment: Not, of course, that I think it (or OP) is sane.  But it satisfies OP's need to not be in the situation of "someone is taking my money (without my permission".

Comment: @RonJohn - I'm often questioning my sanity too. But I'm holding in there, for now. :) As for religious banks - someone taking my money and investing (or lending, or whatever) is exactly what I'm trying to avoid here. In this way the Islam banks aren't any better. My hypothetical non-bank-something-something would be a money _storage_ service, which would also allow access to the stored money via payment cards (aka electronic money). My question was - "Does it exist? If it doesn't exist, why not? (Bonus points if someone has tried and failed, that usually gives valuable insights)"

Comment: @Vilx- I think your question was answered: postal financial systems do more or less what you describe (the counterparty is the government, and it usually has unlimited supply of its own money), but they are going away as commercial banking is much more widespread than it used to and the governments no longer need to provide this service. In the free market there's just no need for such a service, so it doesn't exist. In fact, in some countries (including the US) there's a debate whether the government needs to be involved in the postal service itself.

Comment: @Vilx- JustinCave already told you how expensive it would be to run a "money storage company", and yet you keep pestering.

Comment: @RonJohn Umm, I'm just replying to every comment that comes along. Really, I've already accepted an answer...

Answer (score 1):

There are cultures where any form of interest is considered to be religiously forbidden, I believe. It is possible that these have fee-only banks of the sort you imagine.

But think about it: what are they going to do with the piles of cash they're holding? At some point you or they either wind up having to build and defend your own Fort Knox, or put the money into the banking system as a whole. Heck, even electronic funds transfer itself means you're involved in and to some degree exposed to that system, just as money itself means you're exposed to inflation risks...

There also *used* to be banks in the US that were pure savings-and-loan institutions, whose main exposure was to the loans they issued. Again, that's a different kind of risk, and you need to decide how much you would trust them to pick good loans and to charge interest rates that covered their occasional losses. If this approach appeals to you, many (most?) credit unions still operate on this basis, so that might be an acceptable alternative to your no-investment-risk goal.

Comment: Well, nobody is protected from general economic collapse or inflation. That's fair. But storing piles of cash in a Fort Knox is not what I had in mind. Rather they should store the money electronically as numbers in a database. Physical cash - well, they would need _some_ of it on hand, of course, but most could be given back to the State for safekeeping (with the provision that they can get it back on a moments notice when needed).

Comment: @Vilx-: What you are describing (piles of cash held by the government for safekeeping) is exactly Fort Knox.  Well, likely more bullion than paper currency.  From the bank's perspective, it's also **exactly what SVB did do** -- use the deposits to purchase government bonds.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The difference is that each government already has a Fort Knox by necessity (they _need_ to store piles of cash to release/absorb as necessary). So that each bank does not need to build its own.

Comment: "use the deposits to purchase government bonds" - I don't know any details about SVB or what a "government bond" is. Could they get back the money they paid to get those bonds at a moments notice? I gather from other posts/comments here that not. So it's not the literal kind of money storage that I envisage.

Comment: @Vilx- when you take a loan, do you promise to prepay it in full at a moments notice? Why would the government? Your expectation is unreasonable.

Comment: @littleadv - That's exactly my point. Buying government bonds **ISN'T** "giving money to the government for safekeeping". It's "lending money to the government". Money that doesn't actually belong to the bank and which it had no business lending off to anyone in the first place. But this is getting off-topic. My question was about something else entirely. :) (Though I'd love to rant/debate about economics/banking with someone who understands it more than I do. I feel like I'm really not getting something there.)

Comment: @Vilx- "Rather they should store the money electronically as numbers in a database."  What do they do with the $1500 of cash that I (and all the other people who are paid in cash net taxes) walk in with every other Friday?

Comment: @RonJohn - First of all, they should push for electronic money transfer in the first place (why are you even getting paid in cash this day and age?) However for those people that don't have a choice they could still take that cash and then - as I said - _give it to the government for safekeeping_. Drive it over to the actual Fort Knox that the government has built to store its own cash reserves and leave it in the basement there.

Comment: @Vilx- "they should push for electronic money transfer".  Who is *they*?

Comment: @Vilx- "*give it to the government for safekeeping*. Drive it over to the actual Fort Knox that the government has built to store its own cash reserves and leave it in the basement there."  LOL.  *The government* is going to **LOAN THE MONEY TO THEMSELVES**.  That's what the US does with the Social Security Trust Fund, and I bet it's what **every other country does** too (if they don't loan it to the *US* (or UK or Germany).

Comment: "They" == the imaginary bank-like money-storage company that we're talking about. I'll repeat. I want an institution which **stores money and allows to spend it**, period. It's a part of what banks do currently. You open an account, pay some money into it, get a debit card and go spend it in the shops or whatever. Or you can go to their website, log on to your account and transfer the money to someone else. What this imaginary organization would NOT do is give out any sort of loans to anyone. All the money that was entrusted to them just SITS there, period. [Contd.]

Comment: As for the mountains of physical cash that might accumulate - well, that gets stored in a safe somewhere. One option is that they build their own, but that's expensive. Maybe they could collaborate with someone to make it cheaper. Or they could rent some space in someone else's safe. Or - and this is what I was suggesting before - they could go and rent some space in the safe that the government has built. Or maybe the government would be nice and allow them to use it free of charge. [Contd]

Comment: No matter which safe they use, the cash they put in there, again - just SITS there. It isn't getting used by anyone for any purpose. In the case of the government safe there's a bit of a different approach possible. See, the government can _print and destroy_ money at will, unlike anyone else. So if their safe gets too full, they just shred/burn some cash and get more room. And if it gets low, they print some more.  No matter what they do, their deal with the "bank-thing" stipulates that when the bank-thing wants their money back, they get it back, period. [Contd]

Comment: Worst case scenario, they need a few days to print some more, but they will do it ASAP and the cash will be returned to the bank-thing at the earliest possible moment (though it should really be rare that they're SO much out of stock).

Comment: The religious prohibition in Islam and Judaism is against interest, not loans. Islamic do banks loan your money out, just with different structures. For example, an Islamic bank could invest in mortgages, but those mortgages would be essentially a capital lease (Ijarah). Judaism does not prohibit charging non-Jews interest, so making interest-free loans to other Jews is encouraged by the Torah. Often this is done on a person-to-person basis, which makes it significantly riskier than banking.

Comment: @Vilx: it appears that nobody else wants what you want. Cryptocurrency could theoretically have been it but at this time is subject to speculation, theft, and other ills; even stablecoins don't solve the problem. It sounds like if this is what you really want, you may need to create it, figure out how to actually make trustworthy, figure out how to get the approvals needed so it can interact with other banks... You're looking at megabucks before you can take your first deposit. Plus huge ongoing costs per depositor unless there are many, many depositors. How much is this worth to you?

Comment: @keshlam - Since I don't have any megabucks, I'm afraid all I can do is fantasize and hope that someone with megabucks makes it for me. :) But if nobody really wants it, then I guess that's not going to happen.

Comment: In the UK, you can invest using Shariah banks. Works like a savings account, but instead of interest, you get money paid from the banks profits. If the bank doesn’t make enough profit, you get less (and if you signed up for five years for example you can leave your contract in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Various countries around the world are currently toying with the idea of a so-called ["Central bank digital currency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_bank_digital_currency), which would have the properties you are after - effectively it would be a digital equivalent of the idea of storing cash in a safety deposit box. But there's no significant currency offering that today.

As other answers have explained, banks that lend out deposits do have a vital role in the economy of funding loans. If there was a widespread move to keeping deposits directly with the central bank, the central bank would likely find itself taking on more of the "money creation" role by making its own loans to retail banks which would then lend on to consumers.

Arguably the current situation where central banks are increasingly finding themselves guaranteeing 100% of bank deposits is getting us closer to this situation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Because the FED won´t allow it. There were at least 2 attempts in the US to do it: [Custodia bank](https://custodiabank.com/press/statement-from-custodia-bank-on-federal-reserve-board-action/) and [The Narrow bank](https://twitter.com/saifedean/status/1634429734883926017). In Custodia's case, [FED took incredible 18 month to decide](https://www.coindesk.com/policy/2023/01/27/custodia-bank-denied-federal-reserve-system-membership/), [while it normally takes 5-7 days](https://www.coindesk.com/policy/2022/06/07/crypto-bank-custodia-sues-federal-reserve/), filing a [lawsuit](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/22054891-custodia-federal-reserve) is not necessary, unlike Custodia's case.

Comment: Custodia seems to be a crypto exchange trying to pose as a bank. I found no references other than the linked tweet to the other entity.

Comment: Narrow Bank's homepage: https://www.tnbusa.com/

Comment: didn't go into too many details, but it sounds like a ponzi scheme. Two quotes: "*TNB seeks to serve institutional customers by offering safe depository services at attractive interest rates.*" and "*A narrow bank is a financial institution that issues demandable liabilities and invests in assets that have no nominal interest rate and credit risk.*" cannot both be true. The first quote suggests they do not intend to be a retail bank, so wouldn't be relevant to the OP anyway.

Comment: re crypto exchange: Custodia claims they cannot, by law, take crypto deposits - https://custodiabank.com/roughstock/ - "crypto bank is a misnomer". Serving crypto exchanges is something else than being crypto exchange.

Comment: re: non-retail - ok, so would FED allow a retail full reserve bank? Doesn't seem likely given those precedents. And smaller banks could perhaps use Custodia or Narrow as their bank Or those 2 banks could expand their business. FED's denial surely is a factor, maybe they would fail in the market, but they were not allowed into the market.

Comment: re ponzi: what is so difficult about offering a checking account with 100% reserve and 0% interest rate (and presumably even a fee), and savings account with interest rate but restricted withdrawals (or term deposits)? I guess any bank that offers the two is a ponzi scheme by your definition.

Comment: Even if I accept your explanations (that the two quotes I brought refer to two different products and not to a single one as the actual source appears to show), you're presenting examples of two non-retail banks tailoring to a specific industry whereas the OP is asking about a general retail option. But in reality, this is not a sustainable business model. Ponzi and pyramid schemes always fail. *I guess any bank that offers the two is a ponzi scheme by your definition* - not by *my* definition, any bank that does - is. That's why these banks were not approved.

Comment: [Alex Harris at Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-03-30/cash-stashed-in-money-market-funds-not-banks-fuels-recession-risk-in-wake-of-svb) points out that money market funds are essentially  narrow banks, and they are exacerbating the current banking crisis by enticing deposits away from traditional banks at exactly the moment those banks need deposits.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the numbers.

If I opened a bank-like institution that keeps your money and doesn’t lend it out, I might get 100 million in deposits and say in 10 years I pay the money back with interest. Meanwhile I have to pay for running this bank for ten years. Build a big safe to put the money in and armed guards so nobody just steals it. And I’d like to make some profit. But I make no money.

Even if I kept the cost down to a million a year, in ten years I could only pay back 90 million. I’d have to charge maybe one percent to hold your money for you.

Answer (score -3):

Paying banks a percentage of custodied assets or a flat fee for safe storage definitely has large market demand-- my personal utility curve would probably allow for payments of over 1% the time-weighted average of assets should I get free and unencumbered access to the funds, and I'm someone who never loans more than 250k to commercial banks.

Alas this market demand is part of the reason why the cartel mobilizes to prevent attempts at full reserve banking-- doing so would drain resources from cartel members in a free market. There have been a couple of attempts at such a full reserve model, many of which have been predictably shut down by the regulatory and compliance strangle of the administrative/bureaucratic state. One famous related example is the narrow bank (see for example [here](https://www.spglobal.com/marketintelligence/en/news-insights/latest-news-headlines/narrow-bank-challenges-traditional-industry-model-but-fed-pushes-back-49204495)).

There are a few options to get out of this system, but none perfectly matches your requests.

1. Transform your counterparty to the U.S. government. You can buy T-Bills directly from the treasury at auction or on the secondary market at https://www.treasurydirect.gov/. Holding to maturity guarantees a positive nominal return so long as we don't head all the way back to ZIRP or lower. The flaws with this approach are lock-up periods (i.e. lack of direct liquidity that is available with cash or debt), relatively larger though not huge minimums, inability to invest odd lots, and tax hassle.
2. Introduce additional (small) counterparty and market risk in exchange for liquidity while pursuing the same strategy as 1. You can open a brokerage account and buy something like SHV or BIL, then transfer funds back to a bank account that is funded with requirement minimums whenever you want to make purchases. This carries the same tax hassle as one, but provides better liquidity, has no minimums, and allows for trading with fractional shares. ETFs such as SHV and BIL are collateralized with treasuries, and over the last 15 years, BIL has traded in a range between 91.34 and 92.08. Note that in contrast to directly buying and holding treasuries mentioned in 1, you can lose money in nominal terms here, since the fund is constantly managing maturities to provide investors with a relatively stable duration risk (note that commercial bankers who forgo using rate contracts might stand to learn a thing or two by studying why such management is useful...).
3. Use cryptographic monies. While this meets your criteria, the downsides to this strategy are obvious, though should still be mentioned for completeness. While you may have control over the nominal value of your "account" in cryptographic monies, the purchasing power of this nominal quantity is rapidly changing compared to more stable fiat currencies such as USD, CHF, EUR, or JPY. Apart from that, mass adoption to these newer types of decentralized structures has not occurred, and so transacting in, e.g. BTC, is still a somewhat novel and not near universally available option. It is beyond the scope of the question, but these phenomena's are likely linked-- should cryptocurrencies begin to function as a true medium of exchange by gaining a critical mass in transaction volume, exchange rates would probably be more stable and vise-versa.
4. Keep physical cash on hand, and pay an insurance premium to keep the notional value of the cash safe. This essentially transforms payments you would have paid to a full-reserve bank to an insurance provider. The premium for safety is sometimes forgotten in our digitalized world, and has led to more than a couple of instances where I've witnessed junior traders dream up what they think to be a nice arbitrage involving physical delivery on futures contracts of e.g. precious metals, bring it to the PM, and then come to learn that there is a cost to store and protect gold that they didn't include in their carry calculation.

Comment: But *why* do you want this? What’s the difference between a full-reserve bank and an insured fractional-reserve bank to you, as a depositor, other than the added fees?

Comment: @Kevin Arlin Same reason there is a market for ESG products-- mostly ethical concerns and moral considerations.  Also the idea of no such thing as a free lunch. Protection isn't free, and I view the cost of FDIC to come in the form of moral hazard, a broad increase in prices that wouldn't exist should debt not have been slowly built itself into a requisite for most people to function, and plenty of other issues. I know as an individual I make no difference, but I don't want to contribute to the issues, so opt out as best I can.

Comment: @EDS this makes no sense. Ideology aside, the FDIC cost (just as any insurance) is capped *at most* by the insured amount, where your proposal will be capped *exactly* by the insured amount. So in essence you're proposing to pay the maximum cost of the FDIC insurance whereas for most depositors the insured event never happens and as such the premium for covering the risk is much lower. Economically your reasoning is unsound.

Comment: @littleadv you are neglecting the effects of leverage. But more to the point, the above comment outlines the moral and ethical concerns that impact my personal utility curve

Comment: Right, ideology. Not sure what *effects of leverage* means here, but it's ok to admit that your motivation is influenced by a *belief*, religions are not illegal.

Comment: If the first sentence "...personal utility curve..." and the comment "...mostly ethical concerns and moral considerations..." were confusing to you, then you should not be commenting on week old answers in ways that don't improve the answer